# java.io.FileNotFoundException: build/../AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory) - Robolectric with Multiflavors

Tags: macos, ubuntu, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

My project contains multiflavors and when i try to run the tests on OSX, it works, but when i run it on ubuntu, it throws:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: build/intermediates/manifests/full/fooDev/debug/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at org.robolectric.res.FileFsFile.getInputStream(FileFsFile.java:78)
    at org.robolectric.manifest.AndroidManifest.parseAndroidManifest(AndroidManifest.java:131)
    at org.robolectric.manifest.AndroidManifest.getTargetSdkVersion(AndroidManifest.java:445)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.pickSdkVersion(RobolectricTestRunner.java:430)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:184)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:149)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The flavor name is foo and the second dimension flavor name is dev and the build type is debug.

The path to the full manifest is:

```
build/intermediates/manifests/full/foodev/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
```

and robolectric on ubuntu is looking for:

```
build/intermediates/manifests/full/fooDev/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Why is working on OSX and not on ubuntu?

Comment: Which robolectric version and which robolectric runner do you use?

Comment: I am using roboelectric 3.0 and using android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner. Target sdk = 19

Comment: Ivan from exception I see you are using Robolectric test runner. I would advise you to use RobolectricGradleTestRunner